# Conditionally hide a section header of a grouped tableview with each section having title

Tags: ios, hide, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a condition based on which, I need to hide the header for my static tableView. My tableview's style is `grouped` and every section **has a title** in the section Header.

I am setting the height of the 5th section to `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` because I want it to disappear but it is not working.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if hideFifthRow{
             if section == 4 {
                return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
            }
        }
        return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if hideFifthRow {
        if section == 4 {
            return 0.1
        }
    }

    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}
```

Comment: no that doesn't work because the header title field is not empty.

Comment: Okay. I assumed that title for header is nil that's why you are trying to hide header for that section.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out the reason for header not being able to hide. If there is anything in the header title field, making the section  height to be the smallest possible height will not work.

So, on top of

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if hideFifthRow {
         if section == 4 {
            return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
        }
    }

    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}
```

Here is what I need to perform additionally-

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if hideFifthRow {
         if section == 4 {
            return nil
        }
    }

    return sectionTitles[section]
}
```

Note, I had to store the header titles in an array and set the titles programmatically from `titleForHeaderInSection` delegate method too. For my hiding clause, I had to return nil to get rid of the title first.